# Join multiples tables query SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to simulate a train network. I have 3 main tables in my database, and I need to create one main table with different metrics of each table.

These are my 3 tables with their columns:

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Don't add tags for databases not involved

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This :

    select 
    t1.date, t1.brand, t1.to, t1.met`enter code here`ric1, t1.metric2, 
    t2.metric3, t3.metric4 
into 
    tain_with_metrics
from 
    table_1 t1 
join 
    table_2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date 
               and t1.brand = t2.brand 
               and t1.to = t2.to 
join 
    table_3 t3 on t3.date = t2.date 
               and t3.method = t2.method 
               and t3.type = t2.type;
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question / requirement is. @pierredupont

Comment: @pierredupont, I am not able to understand what you required .. could you please post some sample data and desired sample result, so might be able to clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Is this as per your requirement? @pierredupont

```
select 
    t1.date, t1.brand, t1.to, t1.metric1, t1.metric2, 
    t2.metric3, t3.metric4 
into 
    tain_with_metrics
from 
    table_1 t1 
left join 
    table_2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date 
               and t1.brand = t2.brand 
               and t1.to = t2.to 
left join 
    table_3 t3 on t3.date = t1.date 
               and t3.from = t2.from 
               and t3.to = t1.to
inner join 
    table_2 t4 on t4.date = t1.date
               and t4.to = t1.to
```

Comment: Not sure how that's possible. You can try to create some example tables here - https://www.db-fiddle.com/. I can try to help you out looking at the result set.